# CentOS 5.3 64bit, XEN and DRBD

Tags: centos, xen, drbd

After numerous Google searches and attempts to rectify this issue I decided to post here... hopefully someone here can assist me, please??

I have setup 2 dell poweredge r200 servers with Centos 5.3 64 bit and have installed virtualisation packages (XEN) and DRBD82 , KMOD-DRBD82 etc...

The issue I am having is everytime I try and start DRBD it gives me a "Starting DRBD resources:    Can not load the drbd module." error.  I have tried insmod with a module from my previous kernel but get this error : "insmod: error inserting '....' : -1 Invalid module format"

If I boot up into my previous kernel, DRBD starts and works perfectly??

The kernel I am currently booted into is : 2.6.18-128.1.16.el5xen

Is this a bug with the Centos XEN kernel?? Has someone managed to get it working??

Please help me.... :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!

OK, what I did was :

yum remove drbd82 kmod-drbd82  ## These were the installed packages I had for drbd

yum install drbd82 kmod-drbd82-xen   ## Which will install the XEN related modules

I then configured the drbd.conf and everything starts up correctly now.

Hope this helps anyone else out there.

Comment: This is not really surprising, is it? You had a module installed that was built for a different kernel!

Answer (score 1):

There "shouldn't" be any compatibility issues running Xen and DRBD.

However you will need to rebuild the DRBD module against your new kernel if you haven't already.

The usual approach to this is to reinstall the DRBD package over the existing installation. This will include building the module, by finding and compiling against your new/present kernel sources, ready to use with the new kernel.

Answer (score -1):

hmmmm drbd is slow. View this info: 
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Global_File_System/
GFS is perfect solution for you

Comment: Don't think this really helps: the question is a about DRBD, which can do cluster storage without shared storage, like a SAN. GFS usually needs a SAN, though it can run _on top of_ DRBD. DRBD and GFS are two completely different things: one is a block device (DRBD), one is a filesystem (GFS).